How to improve precision when using float type to compute?
I encountered a problem. The code is as follows:
float a = 2.f;
float t = 0.0000025f;
float b = a + t;
float c = b - a;
    
printf("b = %.8f\n", b);
printf("c = %.8f\n", c);

The output of this program is:
b = 2.00000238
c = 0.00000238

a, b should be stored as float because I need to transfer it to GPU and the OptiX lib only accept float as vertex coordinate type. Then on GPU, I want to get a precise c through b - a.
But now I even cannot get the accurate result in CPU. What I want is b = 2.0000025 not b = 2.00000238 which causes me get a wrong value c = 0.00000238 on GPU. Is there any method I can use to avoid this precision error as much as possible?

Re " What I want is b = 2.0000025 not b = 2.00000238" Given that t and b are float presumably mapped to IEEE-754 binary32, that is not possible. 0.0000025 is not exactly representable as a float, one rounding error. a + t is not exactly representable as a float, a second rounding error. 0x1.000014p+1 => 2.00000238 is in fact the closest available float representation to 0x1.000014f8b5800p+1. Rounding errors means information is lost that cannot be recovered later. Why not pass t to the kernel if you need its value there?

If you need to use float, you need to adjust your expectations.  Getting 2.00000238 instead of 2.0000025 is not "incorrect" or "inaccurate" or "wrong".  It is expected behavior.  (It is merely imprecise — but then, in the real world, virtually all numbers are imprecise.)

So then the question is, what actual problem is it causing you?  Do you have an assertion or unit test that checks whether a value on the GPU is exactly as expected?  If so, adjust that test: it's the test that's wrong.  Or is the roundoff error causing some vital later processing to fail?  Or the end user to see something wrong?  In cases like those, it may be a harder problem to solve.

Actually, a and b are both  one of coordinates of triangles in scene which can be accessed in cuda, and I want to store an integer ID in the form of their difference, then I can obtain the integer ID by b-a. For example, in my code, 0.0000025f is the encoded result of ID 25.

More decimal places which can ensure precision means I can store larger ID in the difference, the way I adopt now is to store an ID over multiple differences and then combine them on GPU.

It is often said that you should never compare floating-point numbers for exact equality.  That's not quite true — there are certain circumstances where comparing for exact equality is perfectly fine — but I'd say this is not one of them.  Your plan to piggyback an ID onto the bits of a float — the low order bits! — is certainly imaginative, but I'm afraid it's going to be quite brittle.

Computing integer ID's from floating point values is madness. You cannot trust the accuracy of floating point. For example, imagine any division by a prime number and all accuracy is out the window. If these are coordinates some 3D/2D? space, just divide the space up into regularly spaced blocks and calculate the ID from the block your coordinate is in. Also, have a look at quad-trees(2D) or oct-trees(3D).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

@Zhixiong Xiao, Tip: when investigating float, use "%.9g", "%.8e" or "%a" rather than "%.8f".

I think you want to use float, because it is faster, or perhaps because it is smaller.
When using float you lose accuracy, especially when adding small numbers to big numbers.
Interestingly, multiplications of numbers of different magnitude do not suffer from this effect nearly as much.
(except when you're exceeding the values float can hold, but that's not accuracy, that's range).
You can solve the accuracy issue for addition/subtraction using Kahan's algorithm.
Here is sample code for CUDA (adapted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kahan-summation-algorithm/)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

template <int count, typename T>
__device__ [[nodiscard]] T kahanSum(T* fa) {
    T sum = 0.0;
    // Variable to store the error
    T c = 0.0;

    // Loop to iterate over the array
    for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        auto f = fa[i];
        T y = f - c;
        T t = sum + y; 
         
        // Algebraically, c is always 0
        // when t is replaced by its
        // value from the above expression.
        // But, when there is a loss,
        // the higher-order y is cancelled
        // out by subtracting y from c and
        // all that remains is the
        // lower-order error in c
        c = (t - sum) - y; 
        sum = t;
    }
    return sum;
}
 
// Function to implement the sum
// of an array
template <int count, typename T>
__device__ [[nodiscard]] T sum(T* fa) {
    T sum = 0.0;
    
    // Loop to find the sum of the array
    for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum = sum + fa[i];
    } 
    return sum;
} 

template <typename T>
__global__ void kahan(const double a, const double b) {
    for (auto r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
        constexpr auto count = 100;
        __shared__ T fa[count + 1];
        for (auto i = threadIdx.x; i <= count; i += blockDim.x) {
            fa[i] = b; 
        }
        __syncwarp();
        fa[0] = a;
        __syncwarp();
        const auto volatile start1 = clock64();
        const auto volatile ksum = kahanSum<count>(fa);
        const auto volatile end1 = clock64();
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            printf("run: %i, %s: kahan: result = %f, time = %i\n", r, sizeof(T) == 4?"float":"double", ksum, int(end1-start1));
        }

        const auto volatile start2 = clock64();
        const auto volatile sumf = sum<count>(fa);
        const auto volatile end2 = clock64();
        if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
            printf("run: %i, %s: plain: result = %f, time = %i\n", r, sizeof(T) == 4?"float":"double", sumf, int(end2-start2));
        }
    }
}
 
int main() {
    kahan<float><<<1,32>>>(2.0, 0.0000025);     
    kahan<double><<<1,32>>>(2.0, 0.0000025); 
    return cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

Here's the link to Godbolt if you want to play with the code:
https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/Pad338Ec5
The timings reported for adding 0.000025 to 2.0 a hundred times are:



type
algorithm
result
delta from true
time in clock cycles




float
kahan
2.000250
-
1784


float
plain
2.000238
0.000012
615


double
kahan
2.000250
-
19265


double
plain
2.000250
-
4830



As you can see, the Kahan summation of 100 elements is ~3x faster than a plain double summation, and the accuracy is preserved.
The plain float summation is ~3x faster still (8x faster than double), but far less accurate.
I store the aray in __shared__ memory to prevent the times from being dominated by memory loads.
So it pays to stay with float at the cost of extra code complexity.
The volatile all over the code is to prevent the optimizer from moving the timing code to the middle of the calculation (thus giving nonsensical timings), you do not need this and can remove it from any code you use.
Limitations
The only reason why this Kahan summation is faster than plain double summation is that on NVidia consumer GPUs there is only one double precision unit per warp, whereas there are (often) 32 single precision units per warp. Because of pipelining issues and such this means in practice double is ~8x slower than single.
It's only 8x and not 32x, because serializing 32 double instructions per warp, means any dependency chains is broken up, which wins back some speed.
On professional GPUs like the A100 and on CPUs this does not apply and there it is faster just to calculate with doubles.

The question asks for 2.0000025, not 2.00025. Kahan summation will not help, because it is impossible to represent 2.0000025 in the format used for float.

So? Use a float2 and represent the value in that. It will still work 3x faster than double, it is quite possible to present 0.0000025 in float, therefor a float2.x for the large part and float2.y small the small leftover will do the trick.

Nice advice which broadens my mind, thank you!

Re “So?”: Because the question states “What I want is b = 2.0000025”, not “What I want is to calculate some multiple of .0000025 added to 2.” If the latter is what OP wants, they should edit the question or enter a new question. But, as it states, the question explicitly states OP wants 2.0000025, and this answer does not answer that question. Kahan summation will not help, and representing 2.0000025 in b while it is a float variable is not possible. In particular, OP states they need to send a float to the OptiX library, so a float2 will not work.

It is possible, just use a float2, as I stated above, precisely using the Kahan summation. That way you can have (some of) the speed of float, with extra precision. Just start with float2 a; a.x=2.0f; a.y=0.0000025f; and take it from there. The answer shows that A: you can start with 2.00000025, and B: do additions without losing precision, and C: do this with floats. It's easy to adjust the code to use float2. That way your summations will run ~3x faster than a double would.

I missed the Optix part, but you can still use float2, just send the float2.x to the Optix library and use the float2 internally. The optix does not need extra accuracy, and if you do than the float2 trick will work just fine. BTW I agree that it is much better to just accept the limitations of float and just work with that, easier, faster and trying to squeeze precision out of floating point (single or double) is a fool's errand.

The precision issue arises from the limited precision of float. To minimize this error you could use double precision. If possible, you could use double for calculations and only convert to float when transferring to the GPU.
I also heard about Kahan summation, but I never actually used it so I can't tell you if this fully applies for your use case.


What I want is b = 2.0000025 not b = 2.00000238…

This is impossible. In the format used for float, IEEE-754 binary32, the nearest representable values to 2.0000025 are 2.000002384185791015625 and 2.0000026226043701171875. No calculation or other operation will ever produce 2.0000025 in a binary32 object.
To get more accuracy, you would have to use a format with more precision, such as double. Alternatively, you might find a different way to calculate whatever you are doing so that the number 2.00000238 is not needed. (For example, it might be possible to rearrange the algebra to work with .00000238 instead of 2.00000238.)

Never did like uncommented DVs.  In this case, the answer is sound. This OP sub-goal is not attainable.
